# Python: Couldn't import magic library

Tags: python, import, jira, libmagic

I'm Python newbie, Recently, I am working a project on JIRA. I need to access JIRA api to retreive some info about issues. But it always indicates as follows:

> WARNING: Couldn't import magic library (is libmagic present?) Autodetection of avatar image content types will not work; for create_avatar methods, specify the 'contentType' parameter explicitly.

And in fact, when I download the magic package with `easy_install` or `pip`, it always fail.

And then, I download the libmagic and magic package manually, copy them to the directory `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages`, but when executing the clause `jira = JIRA()`, it still produces the warning as mentioned above

Comment: How does it fail? You have to be more specific. Try to install `magic` once more and copy the entire console output here.

Comment: I have downloaded the two packages manually and updated the question as above.

Comment: I want to know whether I need to compile the entire lib manually when changed.

Comment: you need to install libmagic and add it to your path

Answer (score 2):

If it is asking for `magic` and `libmagic` it means `libmagic` is not installed, not just the python bindings for it. You need to install that via your package manager from your OS.

Also, if you need help, we can't really help you without tracebacks, so if you're getting errors you need to include those.